# shell: pgp: not found

Tags: pgp, aix

I installed `pgp` on one of my AIX machines (AIX 7.2). When I try to run `pgp` from my id I get the below error:

```
$ pgp
shell: pgp:  not found.
```

But this works as expected using root account.

Can someone say why I am seeing this kind of error?!

```
$ whereis pgp
pgp: /usr/bin/pgp
$ /usr/bin/pgp
shell: /usr/bin/pgp:  not found.
$ echo $0
-shell
```

I tried switch to `ksh`, but still see the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed now. Was a problem with the folder permissions

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/ebs
drwxr-x---    8 root     system         4096 Jan 11 10:42 /usr/local/ebs
$ chmod -R 755 /usr/local/ebs
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     system         4096 Jan 11 10:42 /usr/local/ebs
$ls -ld /usr/local/sbin/
drwxr-x---    2 root     system          256 Jan 11 10:42 /usr/local/sbin/
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/sbin/

$ pgp
Error:  No license file specified. <-- This will go away as soon as my 
licenses are added
```